# Turkish visa required for layover?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, transit-visas, istanbul, turkish-airlines

I am an Indian passport holder. I shall land in Istanbul (IST) airport and within next 4 hours from the same airport I shall take another flight to Greece.

Airline companies for these two flights are different. I have to collect bags and again check in while changing flights as they are not connecting flights.

Do I need a Turkish Visa for this layover?

Comment: @Traveller The cited duplication is for a same-airline transit; this OP will change airlines, which suggests baggage will have to be retrieved and _may_ have to be presented to Turkish customs and _may_ disqualify the OP from "remaining in transit." Not enough information is presented to ascertain whether the cited thread is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: If both airlines are part of the same airline group (Oneworld, star alliance etc.) , it might be worth asking if they could help or route your bags as if it was 1 connecting journey. I don't imagine they will be able to do much, but it's always worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that as these are two separate flights, you will need to go through immigration to claim your bags and check back in.

As your final destination is Greece, I assume you have a valid Schengen visa. If that is the case you can apply for a [Turkish e-visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their
>   travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or
>   USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry
>   e-Visas valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided
>   that they meet certain conditions.

That said, the Turkish MFA website does recommend applying for an e-visa at least 48 hours before departure.

> You can apply for your e-Visa any time before your travel. However,
>   you are advised to create an e-Visa application at least 48 hours
>   before your departure.

Comment: A very good answer!

Comment: After visiting Greece I shall come back to Istanbul and shall visit pamukkale and Cappadocia. Can I have a multiple entry e-Visa? Otherwise, just to collect the bags one entry to Turky will be marked and to enter turkey after Greece, Another entry will be marked. So I will end up in multiple entry. can I apply for two single entry e-visa

Comment: My understanding is that Indian citizens are only eligible for single entry e-visas, so you'd have to apply for 2 separate visas.